# Drivers and value limits on Node Groups

Tags: node-editor, drivers

Let's say you want to use drivers to avoid the max value to be lower than the min value on a node group. As you can see the driver works, the value is changing, but is not limiting the max value.

Video: [click to see the video](https://twitter.com/Sanctus_Art/status/1346445686213144578)

This could be a very good way to make better controls for nodegroups (smarter)

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your thresholds set, disconnect the noodles on the inside of the group and reconnect them.  For whatever reason the values don't update properly while actively in use anywhere down the chain.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok that works but, it should refresh instantly without doing all that, so it is a but.. I mean whatt's the point of a driver if you have to manually refresh it...

Comment: That's what I would think, but it may have something to do with how Groups can be present in more than one place.

Comment: Well, thank you!

Comment: I think it is because of how *Properties* work in Blender, the minimum and maximum values are defined when the property is created, and cannot be changed afterwards, without destroying and re-creating the property. I guess Unplugging / Plugging back the noodles internally force a re-creation of the property. And updating the value of a driver does not trigger that. My 2 cents